# Calculate visible distance with zoom in Google Maps Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a map and I need to calculate the distance with top and bottom of the map having the zoom value and height of the map.

Do you know some pretty solution?

Update:

I write an example solving my own question.

Code: https://github.com/CrisalixLabs/crisalixlabs.github.com/tree/master/map_utilities/visible_area

Working example: http://crisalixlabs.github.com/map_utilities/visible_area/

Comment: Could you edit the question to specify exactly what data you want to use? It's not clear at the moment.

Comment: You would set up a listener for something like `tilesloaded` and then  use the `getBounds()` method to get the coordinates for the current viewport. You'd then calculate the distance between the coordinates for the top right (or left) coordinates and the bottom right (or left) coordinates.  You'll need to make sure that if you use top right coordinates, you use bottom right coordinates, otherwise, you'll be calculating the distance between corners of the viewport.  Here's a related SO question on calculating distance: http://goo.gl/FPWFU

Comment: Thanks! and sorry by short explanation. I can update my answer with code and example.